# Convergence of the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n!} $ using the Cauchy convergence criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Study the convergence of the following series, using the Cauchy Convergence criterion:
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{k!} $$

Following the $ \sum_{k=n}^{n+p} \frac 1{k!} <\epsilon $, I must show that $ \frac 1{(n+1)!}+\frac 1{(n+2)!}+...+\frac 1{(n+p)!}<\epsilon $.

Because $ \frac 1{(n+1)!}< \frac 1{n!} $ and $ \frac 1{(n+p)!}< \frac 1{n!} $ and so on, I get that $ \sum_{k=n}^{n+p} \frac 1{k!}<\frac p{n!} $.

Now I must show that there exista a $ N(\epsilon) $ such that $ \frac p{n!}<\epsilon \  \forall \ n > N(\epsilon) $.

I get two cases:

1. $ \epsilon > \frac p{n!} $ so the inequality holds (this being the simple case).
2. $ \epsilon \leq \frac p{n!} $ in this case I should show that there exists a $ N(\epsilon) $ such that the inequality $ \epsilon \leq \frac p{n!} $ does not hold.

I am stuck on finding that $ N(\epsilon) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Cauchy criterion you need to show that $ \sum_{k = n}^{m} \frac{1}{k!} $ is less that any positive given number if n is n is big enough. So for given $\epsilon$ $$ \sum^{m}_{k = n} \frac{1}{k!} \leq \sum^{m}_{k = n} \frac{1}{n! n^{k-n}} \leq \sum^{m}_{k = n} \frac{1}{n! 2^{k-n}} \leq \frac{2}{n!}. $$
It approaches zero and so for some big n it will be less than this $\epsilon$.